# On hadoop 2.2.0, My datanode could't start up

Tags: hadoop, centos6, hadoop2

everyone, I have a little problem when I build the Hadoop Cluster 
My node install CentOS 6.5,java1.7.60 and hadoop 2.2.0

I want to build a master and three slaves 
I try to build it like [this](http://alanxelsys.com/2014/02/01/hadoop-2-2-single-node-installation-on-centos-6-5/) 
But in the end of this, I try to start up my namenode and datanode

My /etc/hosts like this:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6

10.10.10.10 master
10.10.10.11 slave1
10.10.10.12 slave2
10.10.10.13 slave3
```

Just like this when I type:

```
$ hadoop namenode -fromat:

java.net.UnknownHostException: hadoop01.hadoopcluster: hadoop01.hadoopcluster
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1473)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.DNS.resolveLocalHostname(DNS.java:264)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.DNS.<clinit>(DNS.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.newBlockPoolID(NNStorage.java:914)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.newNamespaceInfo(NNStorage.java:550)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.format(FSImage.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.format(NameNode.java:837)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1320)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: hadoop01.hadoopcluster
    at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:901)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1293)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1469)
    ... 8 more
14/07/01 16:50:46 WARN net.DNS: Unable to determine address of the host-falling back to "localhost" address
java.net.UnknownHostException: hadoop01.hadoopcluster: hadoop01.hadoopcluster
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1473)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.DNS.resolveLocalHostIPAddress(DNS.java:287)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.DNS.<clinit>(DNS.java:58)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.newBlockPoolID(NNStorage.java:914)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NNStorage.newNamespaceInfo(NNStorage.java:550)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSImage.format(FSImage.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.format(NameNode.java:837)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.createNameNode(NameNode.java:1213)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNode.main(NameNode.java:1320)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: hadoop01.hadoopcluster
    at java.net.Inet4AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:901)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1293)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1469)
    ... 8 more
```

and try to issue start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh:

```
$ start-dfs.sh
14/07/01 16:55:23 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting namenodes on [master]
master: namenode running as process 2395. Stop it first.
slave2: starting datanode, logging to /opt/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-datanode-hadoop03.hadopcluster.out
slave1: starting datanode, logging to /opt/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-datanode-hadoop02.hadopcluster.out
slave3: starting datanode, logging to /opt/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-datanode-hadoop04.hadopcluster.out
Starting secondary namenodes [0.0.0.0]
0.0.0.0: secondarynamenode running as process 2564. Stop it first.
14/07/01 16:55:31 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable


$ start-yarn.sh
starting yarn daemons
starting resourcemanager, logging to /opt/hadoop/logs/yarn-hadoop-resourcemanager-hadoop01.hadoopcluster.out
slave1: starting nodemanager, logging to /opt/hadoop/logs/yarn-hadoop-nodemanager-hadoop02.hadopcluster.out
slave3: starting nodemanager, logging to /opt/hadoop/logs/yarn-hadoop-nodemanager-hadoop04.hadopcluster.out
slave2: starting nodemanager, logging to /opt/hadoop/logs/yarn-hadoop-nodemanager-hadoop03.hadopcluster.out
```

and type jps:

```
$ jps
2564 SecondaryNameNode
5591 Jps
2395 NameNode
```

I only look like this, didn't have DataNode, NodeManager, ResourceManger... etc,
Is it any where wrong when I setting it?
Could anyone can suggest me something, thanks!

Comment: Is there a `start-all.sh`?

Comment: yes, but it didn't work too

Comment: What do you have in the log file `/opt/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-datanode-hadoop03.hadopcluster.out` ?

Comment: $ less /opt/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-datanode-hadoop03.hadopcluster.out



/opt/hadoop/logs/hadoop-hadoop-datanode-hadoop03.hadopcluster.out: No such file or directory

Comment: in log folder, did not have this log file

Comment: when you do `stop-all.sh` then `jps` what do you get?

Comment: Stopping namenodes on [master]
master: stopping namenode
slave1: no datanode to stop 
slave2: no datanode to stop 
slave3: no datanode to stop

Comment: Did you install and configure DHCP and DNS ?

Comment: check all the hadoop logs with `grep -i -e error -e warn -e fatal [log-files]`. Sometimes warning in hadoop may lead to an error later

Comment: @Mouna How to do that? I'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

**DHCP** (Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol)

it is a server deployed on an IP network and it is used to allocate IP addresses to its clients. Therefore you had to configure the DHCP on both the server and clients sides.

*On the server side:*

- getting the package: `isc-dhcp-server`
- editing /`etc/network` interfaces to configure interfaces, choose a static IP address for the DHCP server
- specifying the local network interface DHCP will listen to (`/etc/default/isc-dhcp-server`)
- editing configuration file `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf` to choose the IP addresses that will be used by the local network, define the DNS server

*On the client side:*

- editing /etc/network interfaces to configure interfaces

You can make sure that it is well installed and configured you can use `ifconfig` and `ping` commands.

**DNS** (Domain Name System)

- intalling `bind9`
- editing `/etc/bind/named.conf` to add hosts

Good luck.